# Creating a d3 horizontal bar chart with a multidimensional array/nested json file

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, d3.js, appendchild

I'm trying to create a simple d3 bar chart (http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/2/) using the following nested json file.

```json
 {
 "clustername": "cluster1",
 "children": [
 {
 "neighborhoodname": "Shaw",
 "children": [
    {

    "totpop2000": "1005",
    "children": [
    {
        "name": "demographic",
        "children": [
        {"name": "Black", "size2000":0.18},
        {"name": "White", "size2000":0.6},
        {"name": "Hispanic", "size2000":0.40},
        {"name": "Asian", "size2000":0.10}
        ]
        },
    {
        "name": "wellbeing",
        "children": [
        {"name": "Unemployment", "size2000":0.40},
        {"name": "Poverty", "size2000":0.1},
        {"name": "Without HS Education", "size2000":0.31}
        ]
        },
    {
        "name": "crime",
        "children": [
        {"name": "Violent Crime", "size2000":0.09},
        {"name": "Property Crime", "size2000":0.08}
        ]
        },
    {
        "name": "housing",
        "children": [
        {"name": "Home Ownership", "size2000":0.34},
        {"name": "Houses for Rent", "size2000":0.50}
        ]
    }
   ]
   }
  ]
  }
 ]
}
```

So far, my javascript includes the following for adding the amounts labeled as `size2000` to the svg but when I run the code I can't seem to append the appropriate array of data (i.e. I get the first array/`"clustername": "cluster1"`) in my json file.

```js
var data = d3.json("data/test.json", function(json) {
 console.log(json); 

    
var bar = chart2000.selectAll("g")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * height + ")"; });

  bar.append("rect")
      .attr("width", function(d) { return x((d.size2000)*100); })
      .attr("height", height - 1);

  bar.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x((d.size2000)*100) - 3; })
      .attr("y", height / 2)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return (d.size2000)*100); });

});
```

Is there a way to keep the json data structure and append the `size2000` values to a svg? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

One of the basic tenets of visualizations made using D3 is the correspondence between data and elements in the DOM. The mapping *should* also respect hierarchy of the data and DOM nodes, though it is not a strict requirement. Hence, if the data is nested, the visualization *should* be nested in some way as well (e.g. multiple bar charts divided by the hierarchy). Walking this analogy in the other direction, if you want a flat bar chart, then the data *should* also be a flat list of values.

It doesn't have to flat, but it would make the implementation and the DOM mapping easier. I would map the `json` data that you have manually for the bar chart into a flat list:

```javascript
d3.json("data/test.json", function(json) {

    var barChartData = [];
    function addLeaves(node) {
        if (typeof node.children !== "undefined") { 
            node.children.forEach(addLeaves); 
        } else { 
            barChartData.push(node); 
        }
    }
    addLeaves(json);

    var bar = chart2000.selectAll("g")
              .data(barChartData)
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I tried your suggestion, but I am receiving an "undefined is not a function" error for the barChartData.append(node) line. The logic is there, so why would it be undefined...?

Comment: @BYOUNGER That should have been a `push` instead of an `append`. See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you @musically_ut! I was able to push the data.